# JSON Like objects post back

Tags: html, json, post

I've seen in chrome request headers sometimes that you can post back things like arrays and objects for example if I had the JSON object

```
[
    {
        "name":"SmartLemon",
        "age":17
    },
    {
        "name":"Unknown",
        "age":-1
    }
]
```

if this object had the name `foo` then it would be posted back like this:

```
foo[0].name = "SmartLemon"
foo[0].age = 17
foo[1].name = "Unknown"
foo[1].age = -1
```

Im not sure if thats exactly like that but it was similar.

Now lets say I had a table inside a form with lots of rows added dynamically using a jquery template

If I set all the names like so

```
<form method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="Fabian" name="foo[0].name"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" value="17" name="foo[0].age"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="Unknown" name="foo[1].name"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" value="-1" name="foo[1].age"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Would it return the same? Is it the same type of thing? Is there anything wrong with doing this? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use`foo[0][name]` instead of `foo[0].name` in your form, just like following

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="Fabian" name="foo[0][name]"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" value="17" name="foo[0][age]"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="Unknown" name="foo[1][name]"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" value="-1" name="foo[1][age]"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="sub">
</form>
```

On the server side you can retrieve items as given below (`foo` will be one multi dimentional array in the `$_POST` array)

```
$_POST['foo'][0]['name'] // Fabian
$_POST['foo'][0]['age'] // 17
$_POST['foo'][1]['name'] // Unknown
$_POST['foo'][1]['age'] // -1
```

For example, using `php` you can loop like

```
if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
    foreach ($_POST['foo'] as $value) {
        foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
            echo $key . ' ' . $val . '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

Output will be

```
name = Fabian
age = 17
name = Unknown
age = -1
```